# How to swipe and delete

Tags: ios, swiftui, swipe, delete-file

I need help deleting a product I am able to swipe over and delete the product row but the product is not deleting the product is still there when the page refresh how do I fix this code to swipe and delete the product

**This is the full I use to delete the product **

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products: [Product] = []
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    
    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
            completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to convert image to data"])))
            return
        }
        
        let imageName = UUID().uuidString
        let imageRef = storageRef.child("product_images/\(imageName)")
        
        imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            guard let _ = metadata else {
                completion(.failure(error ?? NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to upload image"])))
                return
            }
            
            imageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let url = url {
                    completion(.success(url))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(error ?? NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to get download URL"])))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveProduct(_ product: Product, imageURLs: [URL], completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            completion(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No user signed in"]))
            return
        }
        
        let userId = currentUser.uid
        
        var productData: [String: Any] = [
            "name": product.name,
            "price": product.price,
            "description": product.description,
            "userId": userId // Save the userId along with the product data
        ]
        
        // Convert imageURLs to an array of string URLs
        let imageURLStrings = imageURLs.map { $0.absoluteString }
        productData["imageURLs"] = imageURLStrings
        
        db.collection("products").addDocument(data: productData) { error in
            completion(error)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchProducts() {
        db.collection("products").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching products: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                print("No data found")
                return
            }
            
            let products = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Product? in
                let data = document.data()
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let price = data["price"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                let quantity = data["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0
                let imageName = data["imageURLs"] as? [String] ?? [] // Assuming imageURL is the correct field name
                let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Product(name: name, price: price,  imageURLs: imageName, description: description)
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.products = products
            }
        }
    }
    func fetchCurrentUserProducts() {
        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            print("No user signed in")
            return
        }
        
        let userId = currentUser.uid
        
        db.collection("products")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId) // Assuming you save userId along with product data
            .getDocuments { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error fetching products: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                    print("No data found")
                    return
                }
                
                let products = snapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Product? in
                    let data = document.data()
                    let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let price = data["price"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let quantity = data["quantity"] as? Int ?? 0
                    let imageName = data["imageURLs"] as? [String] ?? [] // Assuming imageURL is the correct field name
                    let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    return Product(name: name, price: price,  imageURLs: imageName, description: description)
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.products = products
                }
            }
    }
    func saveEditedProduct(_ editedProduct: Product, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        guard let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "No current user"]))
            return
        }
        
        // Ensure the edited product belongs to the current user
        let productID = editedProduct.id.uuidString
        
        let documentRef = db.collection("products").document(productID)
        documentRef.updateData([
            "name": editedProduct.name,
            "price": editedProduct.price,
            "description": editedProduct.description,
            // You can update other fields as needed
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error updating product: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(error)
            } else {
                print("Product updated successfully")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
    func deleteProduct(_ product: Product, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
              
              
              let documentID = product.id.uuidString
              
              db.collection("products").document(documentID).delete { error in
                  if let error = error {
                      completion(error)
                  } else {
                      // Successfully deleted
                      completion(nil)
                  }
              }
          }
          
           }    


import SwiftUI

struct ProductNwRw: View {
    var product: Product
        var onDelete: () -> Void

        var body: some View {
            NavigationLink(destination: EditProduct(viewModel: ProductViewModel(), product: product)) {
                       Text(product.name)
                   }
                   .swipeActions {
                       Button {
                           onDelete()
                       } label: {
                           Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                       }
                       .tint(.red)
                   }
               }
           }


#Preview {
    ProductNwRw(product: Product(name: "Sample Product", price: 19.99, imageURLs: ["19.99"], description: "This is a sample product description."
                                ), onDelete: {})
}

import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher
import StoreKit
struct ProductDetailContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ProductViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
                   ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.id) { product in
                       ProductNwRw(product: product) {
                           viewModel.deleteProduct(product) { error in
                               if let error = error {
                                   print("Error deleting product: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                               } else {
                                   print("Product deleted successfully")
                                   // Optionally, you can remove the product from the list
                                   viewModel.products.removeAll { $0.id == product.id }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   .onDelete { indexSet in
                       indexSet.forEach { index in
                           let product = viewModel.products[index]
                           viewModel.deleteProduct(product) { error in
                               if let error = error {
                                   print("Error deleting product: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                               } else {
                                   print("Product deleted successfully")
                                   
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               .onAppear {
                   viewModel.fetchCurrentUserProducts()
               }
           }
       }
    #Preview {
       ProductDetailContentView()
    }
```

Comment: Every time you call `ProductViewModel()` you create a different instance, one does not know about the other. Also, `ObservedObject` is for passing around `ObservableObject`s and `StateObject` is for initializing. I suggest going over some basic tutorials. calling `ProductViewModel()` in the `body` is fundamentally incorrect because it will get recreated unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting a product from Firestore, you should also update the **products array in your view model to reflect the deletion**. This ensures that the UI is updated when the data changes.

Modify your deleteProduct function in ProductViewModel to update the products array after successful deletion:

```
func deleteProduct(_ product: Product, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let documentID = product.id.uuidString

    db.collection("products").document(documentID).delete { error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(error)
        } else {
            // Successfully deleted
            // Update the products array to reflect deletion
            self.products.removeAll { $0.id == product.id }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

and refresh the UI.

```
struct ProductDetailContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ProductViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.id) { product in
                ProductNwRw(product: product) {
                    viewModel.deleteProduct(product) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error deleting product: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            print("Product deleted successfully")
                            // Trigger fetching products again after deletion
                            viewModel.fetchCurrentUserProducts()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchCurrentUserProducts()
        }
    }
}
```

By making these changes, the product deletion should be properly reflected in your UI when the page refreshes after deleting a product. The products array in your view model will be updated, and the UI will be refreshed accordingly. try like this..

Comment: the product still didnt delete I used this to refresh the UI .onChange(of: viewModel.products) { _ in
              // Update the view when products array changes
          } @NewbieiOS

Comment: see the above one and let me know still it is not deleted.